# Aggregating financial data for personal use

Tags: finance

I really like the functionality Mint.com offers with aggregating data from different financial sources into one place. However, the service itself is extremely lacking and I'm curious to know if there are other similar services that also include a programming interface (API)?

I'm preferably looking for a web-based API that I can integrate into something like a Google Apps Script. If it's relevant, my primary banker is USAA.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for Yodlee which is what mint uses under the covers.   http://interactive.yodlee.com/yi-advantage even advocates using their platform to write financial apps that interact with banking infrastructure.